# Multiplying value in div with same class - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many div with the class .price (each one showing a different price) and I have a multiplying factor. When the user choose a radio with determined size, I want to automatically multiply all prices.

I tried the following code, but it is changing for the multiplication of first .price child (All .price is receiving the same price):

```
$('.price').each(function(){
 $(this).html(parseFloat($(this).data('base-price'))*factor);
});
```

How can I multiply the value individually?

Comment: Please post your HTML for us so that we can understand properly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Here is the original code: http://danielgroppo.com/projetaqui/budget.php - I did not post the whole code because the js generates the 'radiobuttons'. The goal is update the prices in the second section of page when choose a option (radiobutton). Each radiobutton has a factor value thats multply all the prices. i did perfectly as the last answer, but it is showing the updated price of first child (try in the example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed the HTML based on your description in the question, Please try.

```js
var factor = 0.5;
changePrice();  
$("input[name='selectRadio']").change(function(){
  factor = $(this).val();
  changePrice();  
});
function changePrice(){
$('.price').each(function() {
    $(this).html('$' + (parseFloat($(this).data('base-price')) * factor).toFixed(2));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" value="10" class="selectRadio" name="selectRadio"/>10
<input type="radio" value="20" class="selectRadio" name="selectRadio"/>20

<ul>
  <li class="price" data-base-price="1.00"></li>
  <li class="price" data-base-price="2.00"></li>
  <li class="price" data-base-price="3.00"></li>
  <li class="price" data-base-price="4.00"></li>
  <li class="price" data-base-price="5.00"></li>
  <li class="price" data-base-price="6.00"></li>
  <li class="price" data-base-price="7.00"></li>
  <li class="price" data-base-price="8.00"></li>
  <li class="price" data-base-price="9.00"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:radio[class=radio-button]').change(function () {
            var factor = $(this).val();
            alert(factor);
            $.each($('.test'), function (index, value) {
                alert($(this).html());
                alert($(this).data('test-value'));
                $(this).html('$' + (parseFloat($(this).data('test-value')) * factor));
            });
        });

        $('input:radio').prop('checked', false);

    });
</script>
```

Here is my HTML code..

```
<input type="radio" value="5"  class="radio-button"  id="rd1"  />first(5)
<input type="radio" value="15" class="radio-button" id="rd1" />first(15)
 <br />
<div class="test" data-test-value="11.8"></div>
<div class="test" data-test-value="11.8"></div>
<div class="test" data-test-value="1.8"></div>
<div class="test" data-test-value="11.8"></div>
<div class="test" data-test-value="9.8"></div>
<div class="test" data-test-value="11.8"></div>
<div class="test" data-test-value="5.5"></div>
<div class="test" data-test-value="4.8"></div>
```

Comment: kindly ignore alert() used for test only..